# Qgis install can't find Gdal framework (Mac OS X 10.7)

Tags: qgis, gdal, installation, framework

After having installed Mac OS X 10.7 I can't install Quantum Gis as it maintains that I have not installe the GDAL Framework, which I have done (several times). Have anyone experienced the same problem (and solved it)?

Comment: It seemed that after having installed GDal 1.9 i could not install the older Qgis 1.7 - sorry for beeing a newbee :)

Comment: I can't remove the question, but i hope you will notice that I have worked it out before answering.

Comment: Answer the question yourself and mark it as accepted. Be sure to be verbose, so the answer could be helpful to others in the same predicament later.

Comment: I understand the instructions on posting which say do not ask a question but I don't have the required 50 reputation points on GISExchange to make a comment. I'm also struggling with installing QGIS on OS X Lion. I've installed GDAL 1.9 and GSL frameworks a couple of times via http://www.kyngchaos.com/ but I still get the "Failure. The GDAL 1.9 framework is required." Error when I run the QGIS installer.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you solved this for yourself but I had this problem as well and had a slightly different solution.

I had already installed GDAL 1.9 via Homebrew but was receiving the "QGIS requires GDAL framework" when trying to install QGIS.  The issue turned out to be that I hadn't installed the GSL framework.  Strange that it was complaining about no GDAL, but after installing KyngChaos' GSL framework, the QGIS install worked.